# Test patterns for testing high speed trans receivers of fpga

Tags: fpga, testing

I know that we can generate all possible patterns using LFSR sequences but this will waste memory as we will have to store pattern to do error checking and storing all from 0 to 2^(n-1) will require huge memory.
So instead of that I want some specific test patterns on which my trans receiver will be faulty. So are there any specific test patterns on which they will give error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to store the whole sequence.  It's possible to feed a PRBS pattern back into a properly-configured linear feedback shift register and get a stream of bits at the output that indicate bit errors.  When done with 'unrolled' LFSRs, this is quite efficient.  See https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-lfsr for code to implement both a PRBS generator and a PRBS checker, both of which have been verified to work on a Virtex Ultrascale FPGA at 25 Gbps.  Also, the high speed transceivers on FPGAs will usually contain PRBS generators and checkers in hard logic for testing links.  It should be possible to place the transceivers in the proper mode and read out the error counters through some combination of control lines and configuration ports.

As for corner cases for testing your receiver, the best I can recommend is just generating and checking a PRBS, especially without more knowledge of your design.

Comment: What do you mean by feeding the PRBS pattern back into LFSR. I mean to ask how will you do error checking if you do not store the patterns ?

Comment: Can you describe how will you do error checking if you don't store all the patterns.

Comment: According to me test patterns should depend on speed, word size, encoding and clocking oh high speed signal. So how to design test patterns for that case ?

Comment: If the pattern is generated by an LFSR, then you can use a 'checker' LFSR that will output one 1 per tap for each bit error.  All you need to do to get the error rate is count up the 1s and divide by the number of taps, so you'll want to add logic to count the number of 1s in each word and accumulate that.  This works even for 2^31 PRBS, which is 2 Gb long.  PRBS works just fine for any word size, each bit just ends up being a shifted copy of the same sequence.  An 'unrolled' LFSR can generate or check whole words of output in each clock cycle.

Comment: PRBS works for any clock speed and word size, and you can send it either directly or encoded if you like.  I don't see how the clocking scheme should have an impact on the test pattern, anything you send is going to have to be properly clocked.  It takes very little logic to generate and check PRBS data, no need for complex logic/state machines, large RAM, etc. which makes it a very common technique.  Also, different sequences have different frequency characteristics and so test the link in different ways - i.e. making PRBS 7 work is much easier than PRBS 31.

Comment: Suppose you have 10Gb ethernet then for that word size is 1500 bytes, encoding is 8b/10b and speed is 10Gb/sec. Also there is another one whose word size is 1000 bytes, encoding is 8b/10b and speed is 3 Gb/sec. Which patterns will you use for testing each one of them ?

Comment: 10 Gb Ethernet uses 64b/66b encoding and 10.3125 Gbps "raw" line rate.  A 10G Ethernet PHY usually presents a 32 or 64 bit XGMII interface to the fabric logic, in which case the word size is either 32 or 64 bits.  Since this design would necessarily use the FPGA internal transceivers, I would use the transceiver internal PRBS generator and checker to test the BER of the physical link.

Comment: Which PRBS and why? Also why people take many different PRBS for testing the same transceiver(PRBS-7,9,23,31 at the same time). Why is that ? Why not only PRBS-31( why they also test with PRBS-23)

Comment: Usually it makes sense to test with the longest PRBS sequence available (PRBS-31).  The other ones are a little bit 'easier' electrically due to the shorter maximum run length of 1s or 0s.  I'm not sure why you would test with shorter sequences, other then equipment support or transceiver performance.

Comment: Do these PRBS sequences repeat over time. Like PRBS-31 will repeat after certain time. So how do we decide that how many times we want a particular sequence to repeat while testing.

Comment: The sequence repeats continuously.  PRBS 7 repeats every 127 bits, PRBS 9 every 511 bits, etc.  Generally BER testing of a system is done for an extended period of time to get enough statistical significance.  For low BER, this can require sending many Gb of data and can take many hours to collect a sufficient number of bit errors.